# Print description doesn't work in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, debugging, xcode6

I put breakpoint and run debug.
The programme stops in this point. I encountered that I couldn't view a valuable description in the debug area after right clicking on the variable, and selecting "Print description".

Nothing displays in the Console area!
Did anyone face this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found out a reason in type of output Console area.
It was necessary to set a type as "all output".